# JLabel won't display the JButton array value

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel

I have a problem with a `JButton` array. I want to display the value of the button in the label box. For example, if I clicked the "1" button I want to see "1" in the `JLabel` box and then if I clicked "4" to have "14" in the `JLabel` box.

This is my code :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class FormSimulateur extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JPanel panneau = new JPanel();
    JPanel clavier, pannAffichage, pannAppelRacc, pannDureeTarif;
    String [] tab = {"1", "2", "3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","*","#"};
    JButton [] btn_chiffre = new JButton[tab.length];
    ListenForButton lfb = new ListenForButton();
    JButton appel, raccrocher;
    Boolean NumOperateur = false;
    JLabel affichage, duree, tarif;
    public FormSimulateur() {
        setTitle("SIMULATEUR D'APPEL TELEPHONIQUE");
        setSize(400,350);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        //panneau.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        setContentPane(panneau);
        Fenetre();

    }
    private void Fenetre() {
        //définition et paramètrage de l'écran d'affichage du numéro composé
        affichage = new JLabel("0");
        affichage.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
        affichage.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(255,30));
        affichage.setOpaque(true);
        affichage.setBackground(Color.white);
        affichage.setFont(new Font("Cambria Math", Font.BOLD, 28));
        affichage.setVisible(true);
        //définition d'un panneau pour le clavier du téléphone
        clavier = new JPanel();
        clavier.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
        //définition d'un panneau pour l'affichage de l'écran
        pannAffichage = new JPanel();
        pannAffichage.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(260,40));
        pannAffichage.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        //création des boutons chiffres
        for(int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++ ){
            btn_chiffre[i] = new JButton(tab[i]);
            btn_chiffre[i].addActionListener(lfb);
            btn_chiffre[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,40));
            clavier.add(btn_chiffre[i]);
        }
        //creation du panneau pour les boutons Appel et Raccrocher
        appel = new JButton();
        appel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,40));
        appel.setText("Appel");
        appel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        appel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD,16));
        appel.addActionListener(this);
        appel.setVisible(true);
        raccrocher = new JButton();
        raccrocher.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,40));
        raccrocher.setText("Raccrocher");
        raccrocher.setBackground(Color.red);
        raccrocher.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD,16));
        raccrocher.addActionListener(this);
        raccrocher.setVisible(true);
        pannAppelRacc = new JPanel();
        pannAppelRacc.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,50));
        //pannAppelRacc.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

        //définition d'un panneau pour l'affichage de la duréé de communication et du tarif
        pannDureeTarif = new JPanel();
        pannDureeTarif.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,95));
        //définition des labels Duree et Tarif
        duree = new JLabel();
        duree.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        duree.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,30));
        duree.setOpaque(true);
        duree.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        duree.setFont(new Font("Courier New",Font.BOLD,14));
        tarif = new JLabel();
        tarif.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        tarif.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,30));
        tarif.setOpaque(true);
        tarif.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        tarif.setFont(new Font("Courier New",Font.BOLD,14));

        //affichage du panneau
        pannAffichage.add(affichage);
        pannAffichage.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        pannAppelRacc.add(appel);
        pannAppelRacc.add(raccrocher);
        pannDureeTarif.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        pannDureeTarif.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Coût et durée"));
        pannDureeTarif.add(duree);
        pannDureeTarif.add(tarif);
        //pannAffichage.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("LCD"));
        panneau.add(pannAffichage, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panneau.add(clavier, BorderLayout.EAST);
        panneau.add(pannDureeTarif,  BorderLayout.WEST);
        panneau.add(pannAppelRacc, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FormSimulateur fr = new FormSimulateur();
        fr.setVisible(true);


    }
    private class ListenForButton implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //String number = ((JButton) e.getSource()).getText();
            String nbre = e.getActionCommand();
            int i = 0;
            do{
            if(nbre.equals(tab[i])){
                affichage.setText(nbre);
            }
            if (!nbre.equals(tab[i])){
                nbre = affichage.getText() + nbre;
            }
            i++;
            //affichage.setText(nbre); 
            }
            while(i < tab.length);
    }

}
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org). Although a better question would have included a description of how your current code behaves.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I've misunderstood your requirements, you don't need a loop. Just this code:

```
private class ListenForButton implements ActionListener {

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String nbre = e.getActionCommand();
    affichage.setText(affichage.getText() + nbre);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah don't need the loop. Unless text button isn't what is to write write on JLabel.

Comment: OK i see with that code definitely don't need the loop because button is created with text on tab[]

Comment: @Duncan Jones +1 maybe to use JTextField#setEnabled(false) instead of JLabel

Answer (score 0):

using @DuncanJone response:

add first variable is better

```
    public class FormSimulateur extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

        boolean first=true;    

        ...

        private class ListenForButton implements ActionListener {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(first){
                    affichage.setText(e.getActionCommand());
                    first = false;
                }
                else{
                    affichage.setText(affichage.getText() + e.getActionCommand());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank's a lot ricardo, are you tested my application? before displaying this number call,i want to load a file who have the number phone registred. The idea is if the user dial a number and click to the button "Appel" the system verified if a number is one of the number in the file? if ok the system display this message "Connected ..." else the system display "Bad number !"

Comment: Write the code if you have problems post you problems and anyone will help certainly

Comment: The first thing is to load a file who all the phone number is recorder and the second is to let the user to dial is number and to click the button "Appel". When all it's ok ie if the number.length is 9 number is the affichage screen, and the number dialed is only composed number, to chrono trigger and print the time who the use have make to pass call after i ought to compute the cost of the call time passed and to print it in the JLabel corresponding.

Comment: Sorry but i'll not write any code for you. My suggestion is to you write and ask if you have problems wth that. If you need to know how you do something you can search about it. If you don't find anything like you need, post a new question and anyone will certainly help.

Comment: ok; i did ask you to write me any code. I just expose the problem and more and gradually i write my code and posted it here. Thanks you

Comment: i suppose you need guidance and i'll help you but not now maybe at night i can help you. But For now do you know anything about Java Files I/O ?

Comment: Your help is welcome. So it's a long time that i don't use Java Files I/O.